# R Reactable - expand by default select groupBy columns

Tags: r, reactable

I have a reactable with two groupBy columns. The default is to start with neither column expanded. Using the defaultExpanded = TRUE argument results in both columns expanded. I would like the default to be only the first groupBy column expanded (i.e., "Type" in my reprex example).

Here is reprex demonstrating, minimally, the structure of my table, the result and the desired, alternate default.

```
if(interactive()){

library(reactable)
library(MASS)

data \<- MASS::Cars93\[,1:3\] %\>%
    arrange(Type) %\>%
    filter(Type == "Van")

ui \<- fluidPage(
    reactableOutput("table")
)

server \<- function(input, output) {
    output$table \<- renderReactable({
        reactable(
            data,
            groupBy = c("Type", "Manufacturer"),
            defaultExpanded = TRUE,
            compact = TRUE
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```

The result:

[image]

The desired default:

[image]

I've tried replacing defaultExpanded = TRUE with defaultExpanded = c("Type"), just in case. No joy. I've also looked in the help for colDef to see if there might be a relevant argument there, but found none I could use. Thanks in advance for any help.